# Displaying data parsed from JSON from Firebase. Cannot get rid of optional string printing

Tags: json, swift, firebase, swifty-json

I am able to properly able to pull JSON data from firebase using this function.

```
func makeLeaderboard() {
    let scoresRef = Firebase(url: "https://URL.firebaseio.com/High%20Scores")

    scoresRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var newItems = [LeaderboardItem]()

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let leaderboardItem = LeaderboardItem(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(leaderboardItem)
            print(item)
        }
        self.leaderboardItems = newItems
    })
}
```

The json data has many objects, that look like this :

```
Snap (-KCIjxAHgGrNnBbL7jsI) {
    ".priority" = "-11";
    Date = "1457398993.668789";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 11;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
}
Snap (-KC3MktapH6Mebw2sAUe) {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457140993.692581";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
}  etc etc etc
```

I am creating leaderboardItem objects from those snapshots. This is the basic struct:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct LeaderboardItem {

let key: String!
var score: String!
let name: String!
let ref: Firebase?


// Initialize from arbitrary data
init(name: String, score: String, completed: Bool, key: String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.name = name
    self.score = score

    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) {
    key = snapshot.key!
    name = snapshot.value["Name"]! as! String!
    score = String(snapshot.value["Score"]) //String(snapshot.value["Score"]!)
    ref = snapshot.ref!
}

func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "score": score,
    ]
  }
}
```

When I go try to display the score property of the leaderboardItem array objects, it is displayed as an optional. No matter how I try to force unwrap the property, it still displays optional.

I am displaying the labels with this code :

```
func populateLeaderBoard() {

    leaderboardScore1.text = "\(leaderboardItems[0].score!) \(leaderboardItems[0].name)"
    leaderboardScore2.text = "\(leaderboardItems[1].score) \(leaderboardItems[1].name)"
    leaderboardScore3.text = "\(leaderboardItems[2].score) \(leaderboardItems[2].name)"
    leaderboardScore4.text = "\(leaderboardItems[3].score) \(leaderboardItems[3].name)"
    leaderboardScore5.text = "\(leaderboardItems[4].score) \(leaderboardItems[4].name)"

}
```

When i run the code, this is the displayed output 
[image]

Comment: You need to unwrap the value e.g leaderboardItems[1].score!

Comment: Can you show us how you populate your `leaderboardItems` array?

Comment: Muhammad, if I do that , nothing changes. You can see that I have already done that with leaderboardItems[0].score! and I still get the optional in the output

Comment: Chris, the array is  filled in the first function i posted. In particular, here:        for item in snapshot.children {
            let leaderboardItem = LeaderboardItem(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(leaderboardItem)
            print(item)
        }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be the problematic line :

score = String(snapshot.value["Score"])

Answer (score 2):

You need to unwrap optional values. You can also do something like this:

```
if let score = leaderboardItems[0].score {
     leaderboardScore1.text = String(format: "%zd", score)
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo for format, but if I run that , I get a display of 2053561456 instead of optional(11) brendan

Comment: Use appropriate format specifier for correct value. In my example i am considering score as Int.